# X86 64-bits Assembly Linux 'Hello World' linking issue

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I am attempting to follow up on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376129/assembly-hello-world-question) which unfortunately does not quite solve my problem. The code I am trying to run is as follows:

```
; File hello.asm

        section .data
msg:    db      "Hello World!",0x0a,0

        section .text
        global main
        extern printf

main:
        push  rbp
        mov   rbp, rsp
        lea   rdi, [msg]  ; parameter 1 for printf
        xor   eax, eax    ; 0 floating point parameter
        call  printf
        xor   eax, eax    ; returns 0
        pop   rbp
        ret
```

My system is debian stretch:

```
$ uname -a
Linux <host> 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.7-1 (2016-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am using the `yasm` assembler as follows:

```
$ yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 hello.asm
```

Because my entry point in the above source is `main` with a final `ret` instruction, I am guessing I need to link with `gcc` rather than `ld -e main`:

```
$ gcc -lc hello.o
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: hello.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This error mentions something about recompiling with `-fPIC` but this is a `gcc` compiler option, not a valid option of the assembler `yasm`. So I don't know what to do here.

Just for the sake of testing, I have attempted to link with `ld`:

```
$ ld -e main -lc hello.o
```

which is successful, but I obtain the same error as mentioned in the above thread when running:

```
$ ./a.out
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory       # The file *is* there ...
```

(following the answer of the thread, I have attempted to compare the `.so` library mentioned in the `ld` binary file with my system's library, and they are both `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.)

I have also attempted to replace the `main` entry point with `_start` (forgetting the issue of properly exiting the program for now) and link with `ld -lc hello.o` but I get the same error 'No such file or directory' as before. I will continue playing with this, but thought I would ask also.

Any working suggestion (with `main` or `_start` , `gcc` or `ld`) would be warmly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
As suggested by Jim I have added `default rel` at the top of `hello.asm` and I obtain a different error message when linking with gcc (no change with `ld -e main -lc`)

```
$ gcc -lc hello.o

/usr/bin/ld: hello.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT2:** This post relates to a failure on `debian stretch`:

```
Linux: 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.7-1 (2016-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
yasm: 1.3.0
gcc: (Debian 6.2.1-5) 6.2.1 20161124
ld: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.27.51.20161220
```

Following on Jim's comment **I have just tested the same code on** `debian jessie` **which works perfectly fine** with `gcc -lc hello.o` and the following versions:

```
Linux: 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
yasm: 1.2.0
gcc: (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
ld: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.25
```

**EDIT 3:** Pending a formal answer from Michael Petch: **issue resolved with** `gcc -static hello.o`

Comment: Your code actually works for me (on a different distro).  Your problem seems to be related to the relocation type of `hello.o`.  I would suggest adding the directive `default rel` to the top of `hello.asm` and see if that works or provides a different error.  Are you deliberately trying to use R_X86_64_32 relocation?

Comment: @JimD. thank you very much for your help. I have edited my post to indicate new error message.

Comment: What happens if you build statically with `gcc -static hello.o`

Comment: @MichaelPetch You got it !!! `gcc -lc -static hello.o` works perfectly (on the `debian stretch` machine). Incidentally, it also works on `debian jessie`. If you want to write an answer, I will gladly validate it. Any insight as to what may be happening is also very welcome (but i don't want to take too much of your time). Thank you very much !!!

Comment: OK, so now we made it past the data section, but have trouble with the text relocation. I like @MichaelPetch suggestion of trying an explicitly static build.  But why are you explicitly adding `-lc` when linking?  Maybe try just `gcc hello.o` and see if you get a different result?

Comment: @JimD.good point the `-lc` option is unnecessary with `gcc` (got it as a habit from `ld`). However `gcc hello.o` leads to the same errors (with or without `default rel` on top of `hello.asm`), while `gcc -static hello.o` is successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC in Debian Stretch [defaults to building position independent executables](https://wiki.debian.org/Hardening/PIEByDefaultTransition), to build executable linked to specific address as is traditional pass `-no-pie` to GCC.

Alternatively specify the correct relocation type, I don't know how to do this in yasm.

Comment: Hi Timothy, while `gcc -static hello.o` is successful, the linking command `gcc -fno-pie hello.o` fails on my `debian stretch` machine. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `-no-pie` when linking, `-fno-pie` controls compiling.

Comment: Thank you Timothy, both `gcc -static hello.o` and `gcc -no-pie hello.o` work perfectly !

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux