# Why do I get oveflow in printf?

Tags: c, assembly

Hey I have to call a function of glibc in assembly for an exercise. So I found this code to call printf.

```
section .rodata
    format: db 'Hello %s', 10
    name:   db 'Conrad'

section .text
        global main
        extern printf
    main:
        ; printf(format, name)
        mov rdi, format
        mov rsi, name
        call printf
        ; return 0
        mov rax, 0
        ret
```

But i get the error:

Symbol `printf' causes overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation

Compiled it with:

nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.asm

gcc -o test test.o

The error occurs after doing

./test

Comment: Add `\0` to `format` and `name`.

Comment: The same mistake

Comment: @eanmos: That's a separate problem.

Answer (score 3):

Change `call printf` to `call printf@PLT`. The former only works if the actual definition of `printf` is withing ±2GB of the `call` instruction, which can't be known if the definition is in a shared library (it would work if you static link, though). "Overflow" is telling you that the relative address, which would need to be up to 64-bit, overflows in a 32-bit call instruction offset.

By using `printf@PLT`, you'll instead get a relative address that resolves statically at link time to a thunk in the PLT, which loads and jumps to the address of the function definition, resolved at dynamic-linking time.

As Maxime B. noted, the loads of the addresses of `format` and `name` are also not correct for position-independent code. They should be loaded with "rip-relative" form, but it looks like you're using the weird "Intel syntax" for asm and I'm not sure how to write it in that syntax. You could, as Maxime B. suggested, build with `-fno-pie`, but better would be figuring out the way to fix your code so it doesn't depend on being linked for a particular fixed address.

Comment: for me @plt is undefined

Comment: @JanWolfram: It might be nasm expecting it to be written in some odd way (again, I'm not familiar with the syntax it uses) or it might just be that you introduced extra spaces or something else wrong in the syntax.

Comment: @JanWolfram For NASM you may want to consider `call printf wrt ..plt` . `call printf@plt` would be GNU assembler syntax

Answer (score 2):

You should compile your with `-no-pie`

This error is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123505/assembling-with-gcc-causes-weird-relocation-error-with-regards-to-data). Quoting the original post:

> Debian switched to PIC/PIE binaries in 64-bits mode & GCC in your case is trying to link your object as PIC, but it will encounter absolute address in mov $str, %rdi.

Comment: Then I only have segmentation fault

Comment: @JanWolfram Which is probably due to the lack of '\0' at the end of the strings as pointed out by eanmos

Comment: :/ no thats not the error. Sorry for my bad knowledge

Comment: @JanWolfram: and because you didn't align the stack before calling `printf`.  (And didn't set AL=0 so it will save the XMM regs to its register-save area with aligned stores, so this ABI violation will likely crash *in practice*).